# Static instances of class Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, static

I've a main class that contains main method as well as start method. Now I've a lot of other classes also. For example I've a login class, signup class and so on. I've a class that just handles the data of currently logged on user. that class is needed to be accessed from a lot of controllers. As this user is always gonna be only one so one instance of class. What i want to know what is the best approach so every class can access it update it.

What I'm currently applying is I'm making a static instance of logged user data type class in my main class. and then accessing them.

```
    public static loggedUserData user  = new loggedUserData();
```

then accessing it from anywhere as:

```
    demo.user.set(...);
```

While class methods and fields are non static. I think there could be a better way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `user` object is application data that forms part of the model in MVC/MVP etc designs:

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class DataModel {
    private ObjectProperty<User> currentUser = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public final ObjectProperty<User> currentUserProperty() {
        return this.currentUser;
    }

    public final User getCurrentUser() {
        return this.currentUserProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setCurrentUser(final User currentUser) {
        this.currentUserProperty().set(currentUser);
    }



    // other properties, etc...
}
```

In relatively simple applications, I create a singleton [controller factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setControllerFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) that references a model instance and passes it to any controller constructor that can accept it:

```
package application;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

import javafx.util.Callback;

public enum ControllerFactory implements Callback<Class<?>, Object> {

    INSTANCE ;

    private final DataModel model = new DataModel();

    @Override
    public Object call(Class<?> type) {
        try {
            for (Constructor<?> constructor : type.getConstructors()) {
                if (constructor.getParameterCount() == 1
                        && DataModel.class.isAssignableFrom(constructor.getParameterTypes()[0])) {
                    return constructor.newInstance(model);
                }
            }
            return type.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

(Another option, instead of using a singleton pattern here, is just to have a constructor that accepts a `DataModel` and be careful to always pass a reference to the same `DataModel` instance. Often it is quite natural to do this.)

Then you can have controllers that look like

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class LoginController {

    private final DataModel model ;

    @FXML
    private TextField userNameTextField ;

    public LoginController(DataModel model) {
        this.model = model ;
    }

    @FXML
    private void login() {
        model.setCurrentUser(new User(userNameTextField.getText()));
    }

}
```

and

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class SomeOtherController {

    private final DataModel model ;

    @FXML
    private Label userLabel ;

    public SomeOtherController(DataModel model) {
        this.model = model ;
    }

    public void initialize() {

        // Use EasyBind https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind for
        // more robust binding to a "property of a property"

        userLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.select(model.currentUserProperty(), "userName"));
    }
}
```

The controllers will be automatically populated with the (shared) data model if you use the following idiom to load your FXML files:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        String resource = "Login.fxml" ;
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));
        loader.setControllerFactory(ControllerFactory.INSTANCE);
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

For more complex applications (or simply if you prefer a convention-based/opinionated approach), consider using a dedicated JavaFX dependency injection framework such as [Afterburner.fx](https://github.com/AdamBien/afterburner.fx/).

Comment: How about if i get controller from fxml loader and set user data object in loaded controller?

Comment: You can do that, but then you end up having to repeat that "wiring" code every time you need it. You also have to carefully ensure you pass in the "correct" user data object reference. At some point, you will likely find there are other data you need to share, and then your code will start to get pretty convoluted using that approach.